# Can't use SDL Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with SDL and I'm doing a simple threading task but I always get these errors:

```
argument of type "int (mainGame::*)(void *ptr)" is incompatible with parameter of type "int (__cdecl *)(void *)"
```

The other error I'm getting:

```
error C3867: 'mainGame::gameEvents': function call missing argument list; use '&mainGame::gameEvents' to create a pointer to member
```

This is how the function is written:

```
int gameEvents(void *ptr){
   //do things here.
return 0;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to call the function:

```
SDL_Thread* gh;  
 gh = SDL_CreateThread(gameEvents,NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using C++, you need to declare your function with C linkage, since that's what SDL expects, being a C library itself:

```
extern "C" int gameEvents(void *ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I did get some additional error IntelliSense: linkage specification is not allowed but I just had to take the function out of the class. The function has to be at file level.

Answer (score 1):

Change `gameEvents()` to `static`.  Otherwise your member function will have a "hidden" first argument for the `this` pointer that C APIs like SDL don't know about.

If you need access to instance data do something like this:

```
static int mainGame::gameEvents(void *ptr)
{
   mainGame* game = (mainGame*)ptr;
   //do things here.
   return 0;
}

...

mainGame game;
SDL_Thread* gh;  
gh = SDL_CreateThread( mainGame::gameEvents, &game );
```